# How to display RML custom header and footer in all page

Tags: openerp-7, rml

I add my own custom header and footer in RML report, the problem is when I select all the record and print, first page prints correctly, the problem occurs in second page, header and report data overlapped, so how to set header in all the pages without overlapping

```
<template title="High_Value_Item" author="OpenERP S.A.(sales@openerp.com)" allowSplitting="20">
<pageTemplate id="first">
  <frame id="first" x1="30.0" y1="27.0" width="508" height="815"/>
    <pageGraphics>
        <image x="1.3cm" y="26.0cm" height="90.0">[[company.logo or removeParentNode('image')]]</image>
        <place x="16.6cm" y="25.3cm" height="1.8cm" width="15.0cm">
        <para fontSize="7.0" fontName="Helvetica" >[[ display_address(company.partner_id) or  '' ]]</para>
        </place>
        <lines>1.3cm 24.9cm 19.9cm 24.9cm</lines>
    </pageGraphics>
</pageTemplate>
```

The above code from my RML report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
<template title="High_Value_Item" author="OpenERP S.A.(sales@openerp.com)" allowSplitting="20">
    <pageTemplate id="first">
    <frame id="first" x1="8.7cm" y1="5.0cm" height="24.0cm" width="21.5cm"/>
    <pageGraphics>
        <image x="1.3cm" y="26.0cm" height="90.0">[[company.logo or removeParentNode('image')]]</image>
        <place x="16.6cm" y="25.3cm" height="1.8cm" width="15.0cm">
            <para fontSize="7.0" fontName="Helvetica" >[[ display_address(company.partner_id) or  '' ]]</para>
        </place>
        <lines>1.3cm 24.9cm 19.9cm 24.9cm</lines>
    </pageGraphics>
</pageTemplate>
```

I coded in air so if any content comes in undesired place than you may change the *x* and *y* coordinate.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks friend, its work fine and I changes x and y coordinates according to my need.