# How to specify a margin top for pto_header in RML?

Tags: report, odoo, openerp-7, rml

I am doing a report which is going to have a lot of lines, therefore it is going to be composed by several pages.

I declared a `pto_header`, because I want it to be shown at the top of each page. The problem is that it is always totally attached to the external header of the report, which does not look good. I would like to specify a margin-top for my `pto_header` (which is a `blockTable`).

By the moment, I was not able to manage it. I tried to include a couple of `<para>` with the attribute `spaceBefore`, but they are ignored in each page except for the first one.

```
...
<stylesheet>
  ...
  <paraStyle name="terp_header" fontSize="15.0" leading="20" alignment="CENTER" spaceBefore="20.0" spaceAfter="20.0"/>
</stylesheet>
<story>
  <pto>
    <pto_header>
      <para style="terp_header"></para>
      <para style="terp_header"></para>
      <blockTable colWidths="480.0">
        <tr>
            <td>
              <para>Name</para>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </blockTable>
    </pto_header>

    <para style="terp_header"></para>
    <para style="terp_header"></para>
    <blockTable colWidths="480.0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <para>Name</para>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </blockTable>
  ...
  </pto>
</story>
...
```

I was taking a look to the code of other standard reports, and in fact, they look bad, because they do not respect the margin and their internal headers are totally sticked to their external headers.

Can anyone help me, please? My solution only works for the first page. It must be a better way to manage this.

Comment: check out this, might be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26481548/how-to-display-rml-custom-header-and-footer-in-all-page/26483996#26483996

Comment: @Odedra I have been trying the solution you gave to that guy for several hours but I'm not able to manage it. I think I don't understand very well how the frames work. I have read the RML user guide but I wasn't able to understand that part.